Selecting rows that compose largest group (within another group) in a pandas DataFrame
Main problem
I'm trying to find a way to select the rows that make up the largest sub-group inside another group in a Pandas DataFrame and I'm having a bit of a hard time.
Visual example (code below)
Here is a sample dataset to help explain exactly what it is I'm trying to do. There is code below to recreate this dataset yourself, if you'd like.

Suppose I want to group this table by Col1 and figure out which unique value of Col2 has the most rows (within each group of Col1). Further, I don't want to just know which group is the largest - I want to find a way to select the rows from the original DataFrame that match that description.
So, in this case, we can easily see that, for Col1=="Group A", the value of Col2 with most rows is "Type 3", and for Col1=="Group B", the value of Col2 with most rows is "Type 6".
That means that I want to select the rows with RowID in [10005, 10006, 10007, 10008, 10009, 10010, 10011, 10012, 10013, 10014, 10015].
Therefore, the output I'm looking for would be the following:

My clumsy attempt
I found a solution, but it is tremendously convoluted. Here is a step-by-step explanation of what I did:
Step 1: First, for each group of Col1, I want to tally up the number of rows that exist for each unique value of Col2. That's quite easy, I can just do a simple groupby(['Col1','Col2']) and see the size of each grouping.
Here is how that looks:

Notice that for Col1=="Group A", Col2=="Type 1" has 2 observations, Col2=="Type 2" has 2 observations, and Col2=="Type 3" has 6 observations - as expected from our original data.
Step 2: This is trickier: for each group of Col1, I want to find the value of Col2 that has the biggest number of rows from Step 1.
Here is how that looks:

Notice that we only see the cases with "max rows".
Step 3: Lastly, I want to filter the original data to show ONLY the rows that fit that specific grouping: the ones found in Step 2.

Reproducible example and code
Here's some code to illustrate my example:
# Importing the relevant library
import pandas as pd

# Creating my small reproducible example
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'RowID':[10001,10002,10003,10004,10005,10006,10007,10008,10009,10010,10011,10012,10013,10014,10015,10016,10017,10018,10019,10020],
                      'Col1':['Group A','Group A','Group A','Group A','Group A','Group A','Group A','Group A','Group A','Group A','Group B','Group B','Group B','Group B','Group B','Group B','Group B','Group B','Group B','Group B'],
                      'Col2':['Type 1','Type 1','Type 2','Type 2','Type 3','Type 3','Type 3','Type 3','Type 3','Type 3','Type 6','Type 6','Type 6','Type 6','Type 6','Type 3','Type 3','Type 2','Type 2','Type 2'],
                      'Col3':[100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,2000,1900,1800,1700,1600,1500,1400,1300,1200,1100],
                      'Col4':['Alice','Bob','Carl','Dave','Earl','Fred','Greg','Henry','Iris','Jasmine','Kris','Lonnie','Manny','Norbert','Otis','Pearl','Quaid','Randy','Steve','Tana']})

# Solving Step 1: finding the unique groupings and their relative sizes
temp1 = my_df.groupby(['Col1','Col2']).agg({'RowID':'count'}).reset_index()

# Solving Step 2: finding which grouping is the largest
temp2 = temp1.groupby(['Col1']).agg({'RowID':'max'}).reset_index()

# Solving Step 3: finding which rows of the original DataFrame match what was 
# found in Step 2

# Step 3 Part 1: Finding the actual combination of `Col1` & `Col2` that let to 
# the largest number of rows
temp3 = (temp1
         .rename(columns={'RowID':'RowID_count'})
         .merge(temp2
                .rename(columns={'RowID':'RowID_max'}), 
                how='left', 
                on='Col1')
         .assign(RowID_ismax = lambda _df: _df['RowID_count']== _df['RowID_max'])
         .query('RowID_ismax')
         .drop(columns=['RowID_count','RowID_max']))

# Step 3 Part 2: Finding the matching rows in the original dataset and 
# filtering it down
result = (my_df
          .merge(temp3, 
                 how='left', 
                 on=['Col1','Col2'])
          .assign(RowID_ismax = lambda _df: _df['RowID_ismax'].fillna(False))
          .query('RowID_ismax')
          .reset_index(drop=True)
          .drop(columns=['RowID_ismax']))


The solution above is EXTREMELY convoluted, full of assign and lambda statements alongside several sequential groupbys and reset_indexs, which suggest to me I'm approaching this the wrong way.
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

A short code to perform this could value_counts + idxmax, then merge:
keep = my_df[['Col1', 'Col2']].value_counts().groupby(level='Col1').idxmax()

out = my_df.merge(pd.DataFrame(keep.tolist(), columns=['Col1', 'Col2']))

Output:
    RowID     Col1    Col2  Col3     Col4
0   10005  Group A  Type 3   500     Earl
1   10006  Group A  Type 3   600     Fred
2   10007  Group A  Type 3   700     Greg
3   10008  Group A  Type 3   800    Henry
4   10009  Group A  Type 3   900     Iris
5   10010  Group A  Type 3  1000  Jasmine
6   10011  Group B  Type 6  2000     Kris
7   10012  Group B  Type 6  1900   Lonnie
8   10013  Group B  Type 6  1800    Manny
9   10014  Group B  Type 6  1700  Norbert
10  10015  Group B  Type 6  1600     Otis

Intermediates:
# my_df[['Col1', 'Col2']].value_counts()
Col1     Col2  
Group A  Type 3    6
Group B  Type 6    5
         Type 2    3
Group A  Type 1    2
         Type 2    2
Group B  Type 3    2
Name: count, dtype: int64

# my_df[['Col1', 'Col2']].value_counts().groupby(level='Col1').idxmax()
Col1
Group A    (Group A, Type 3)
Group B    (Group B, Type 6)
Name: count, dtype: object

Alternatively, with groupby.transform (which would select multiple groups if there are multiple ones with the maximum size):
s = my_df.groupby(['Col1', 'Col2']).transform('size')
out = my_df[s.groupby(my_df['Col1']).transform('max').eq(s)]


This is great, thank you so much!
